# PyCharm - Is there a way to display the detected file type?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Sublime Text uses `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P` for this. This shortcut responds with a popup widget which says e.g. `text.html.mako`. Is there a similar shortcut in the JetBrains family of products?

Comment: What's the use case? PyCharm file types are defined per extension [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-registering-file-types.html). You can tell the type by the file icon.

Comment: Well, the use cases... First, the way PyCharm works with Mako templates is less than ideal; there were times when I wasn't sure if a given `.mako` file was really recognized as Mako. Second - it is possible to setup PyCharm to treat `.html` files as Mako. And I'd love to have a simple way (read: a shortcut) to make sure that the detection worked. Third (and this has nothing to do with Mako, finally) - once I tried to create my custom type for Language Injection. It didn't work and I was missing a simple tool to at least check that the newly defined types was recognized.

Comment: You can try this plug-in: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7404-override-file-language. It will show the file type in the status bar.

Comment: CrazyCoder - Thank you, this solves my problem with file type detection based on `.html` vs `.mako` extensions. Would you convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a third-party plug-in [Override File Language](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7404-override-file-language) which shows the file type in the status bar and allows to quickly change it.